# Ternary conditional logic in Karate with undefined variable

Tags: nashorn, karate

I have a Karate feature file, let's called it *A.feature*, that is intended to be re-used by other feature files. By using shared scope, *A.feature* can use some variables, for instance the country, defined in the calling feature file. I want these parameters to be optional, but with a default value defined in *A.feature*. To do that I'm using ternary conditional logic, for instance:

```
* def myCountry = (country ? country : 'us')
```

However when *country* is not defined, a

> ReferenceError: "country" is not defined

is thrown.

Does anybody have any idea how to resolve that, or if there is a Nashorn or Karate bug ?

If you want the complete stacktrace let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work:

```
* def country = typeof country == 'undefined' ? 'us' : country
```

EDIT - Karate now has a convenient API to do this:

```
* def country = karate.get('country', 'us')
```

Comment: Super, you're the best. Do you know if it's a Nashorn or Karate bug ?

Comment: well, this is a unique combination of how karate embeds nashorn. IMO this is the right behavior - I personally discourage having "undefined" variables. may impact maintainability in the long term. you can argue that it has value in re-usable situations like your case

Comment: Karate doesn't have support for the new method of `* def country = country === undefined ? 'us' : country`
I was able to get the new method to work in a .js file, but in a feature file I had to use the answer listed above.  On 1.2.0.RC2

Answer (score 4):

A simpler way is to use [default values](https://intuit.github.io/karate/#default-values):

```
* def country = karate.get('country', 'us')
```

Comment: thanks ! yes, default values for `karate.get()` were a new addition to the syntax