# optional scenario argument in Karate doesn't work

Tags: karate

I need to use a variable say 'country' in my scenario that some parent scenarios do provide the value for, but some - don't. I know how to check if the value is provided:

```
    * def country = karate.get('country', 'us')
```

But how to create / specify such variable in my scenario and in parent scenarios?

Comment: sorry I read your question a few times and could not understand it. can you provide a very simple example so that someone can cut and paste it and try ? or follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - there is no such as thing as `step()` or `scenarioArgs` in karate

Comment: I have same situation as (you answered) in
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310416/ternary-conditional-logic-in-karate-with-undefined-variable

Same description. May be my problem is in the area of "shared scope" (what is it?) as it's exactly what I need:
"By using shared scope, A.feature can use some variables, for instance the country, defined in the calling feature file." I mean how to have such variable?

Comment: maybe you should read the documentation ? https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-other-feature-files

Comment: I've just read the above and still my question exists:
on https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#default-values
it explains exactly what I need  but what I don't get is how that variable 'foo':
(a) is specified in the "called" scenario (or not at all?)
(b) how this 'foo' variable is specified in the "caller" scenario that does want to define it.
.....
I mean, some example of what happens with 'foo' variable in "caller" and "called" right before
* def foo = karate.get('foo', 42)

Comment: sorry I pass. someone else may be able to understand your question and help, all the best

Comment: could you please just give me an example with that 'foo' variable - how it's defined in the "caller" scenario and whether it's defined (or not) in "called" scenario

Comment: this was in the link I provided, but hey - here you go: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callfeature/call-feature.feature

Comment: Big thanks! Probably my ignorance was due to the very late evening reading :-)